# Use a macro that expands as tikz code as content for forest

Tags: tikz-styles, forest

I'm trying to produce a tree that sets the content of each node as a table.

My attempt is like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\tikzset{
table/.style={%
  rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1,
  draw, minimum width=1cm,
  rectangle split part align={center}
},
}
% Test with this, got an '! Missing \cr inserted.' error
\newcommand{\vals}[3]{#1\nodepart{two}#2\nodepart{three}#3}
% I suspected of a expansion problem, try this
% Now it compiles, but it doesn't produce the parts of the node
\newcommand{\valsnx}[3]{#1\noexpand\nodepart{two}#2\noexpand\nodepart{three}#3}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
  parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,
  font=\ttfamily,
  align=center,
  align=center,
  node options={table=3},
},
[
%  [{a\nodepart{two}b\nodepart{three}c}]% doesn't work either
%  [\vals{a}{b}{c}]% doesn't work
  [\valsnx{a}{b}{c}]% works but doesn't produce the \nodepart structure I'm looking for
  []
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

I'm using `rectangle split` to produce the table-like node. However, when I try to produce content that is split using the `\nodepart` I got an `! Missing \cr inserted.`.

I suspected of an expansion problem. Something in the lines that when the forest is parsed my macro `\vals` is expanded and then the `\nodeparts` are expanded in the following parsing of the forest and thus producing the error. Try to put a `\noexpand` within the macro (and on the macro itself, as `\noexpand\vals`) but that didn't work.

Can someone explain what am I missing? and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you please expand the MWE to include one correct node (without `\vals`, but just directly with `\nodeparts`)?  I find it difficult to combine `\nodeparts` and `forest`s.

Comment: That is the problem, I can't make it work either with just `\nodepart`s. If you see my example, the first commented node is my attempt to use it with `forest`.

Comment: OK. Back up a little. What are you actually trying to *do*? I am pretty sure there are better ways of doing it ....

Comment: My idea was to typeset some table-like nodes. I was trying to use the `tikz` `rectangle split` to make that happen. So, I tried to put the style on the node specification, and then the content on each bracket in the tree. However, the `\nodepart` doesn't work.

Comment: You're making it too complicated. Multiline nodes already are tabulars. If you prefer a different specification for the columns etc.,  you just say so with `align`. Right now, you are trying to put a multi-part node inside a tabular node and I don't think that is going to work very easily ;).

Comment: `\vals` macro will work if you omit (the two) `align=center`. That being said, listen to what @cfr said ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code was written for **forest** version 1. It compiles without modification with version 2 with the same output (as far as I can tell).

---

Why make life difficult for yourself? `align` sets a tabular header. Multiline nodes just are tabulars in a **forest** tree. `center`, `left` and `right` just set an appropriate tabular header.

If you don't want one of the default choices, you can use a different one. For example, I defined a new **forest** style, `forest table`:

```
\forestset{
  forest table/.style={
    align={|C{#1}|},
    inner sep=0pt,
    before typesetting nodes={
      if content={}{
        shape=coordinate
      }{},
    },
    draw
  },
}
```

The key setting here is `align` which uses a custom column type `C` column defined with `\newcolumntype{}{}` from the `array` package:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

If you always want the same width, you can say

```
  forest table/.style={
    align={|C{10mm}|},
    ...
```

or whatever instead.

The remaining settings are just to make the output prettier (to my eyes) by ensuring that the branches are drawn to meet the table boundaries:

```
    inner sep=0pt,
    ...
    draw
```

and that empty nodes are integrated smoothly into the drawn edges:

```
    before typesetting nodes={
      if content={}{
        shape=coordinate
      }{},
    },
```

Then you can use `\hline` etc. within the node to create the horizontal lines and define your command as a wrapper around the values which just inserts the row endings and rules. For example, I used

```
\newcommand{\vals}[3]{\hline#1\\\hline#2\\\hline#3\\\hline}
```

Then

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    forest table=10mm
  }
  [
      [\vals{a}{b}{c}]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

will produce a tree like this:

[image: tabular in tree node]

This works fine if you want an empty table in a node, while also allowing truly empty nodes:

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    font=\ttfamily,
    forest table=25mm,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    }
  },
  [\vals{}{}{}
    [\vals{a}{b}{c}
      [
        [\vals{Node above}{deliberately}{left empty}]
      ]
    ]
    [\vals{d}{e}{f}]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

produces

[image: Empty tables and empty nodes]

Although your question didn't mention this, you suggest in comments that you would like empty nodes to become empty tables. This is relatively straightforward. We can define a `forest tables=<width>` style in the same way as the `forest table=<width>` style. In fact, we can define the former using the latter.

Specify the width of columns as before, passing this to the `forest table` style:

```
  forest tables/.style={
    forest table=#1,
```

If the node has no content, make a table here anyway:

```
    delay={
      if content={}{
        content={\vals{}{}{}},
      }{}
    }
```

The `delay` ensures that if a node does have content, it is not overwritten by an empty table.

```
  }
```

Then

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    font=\ttfamily,
    forest tables=10mm,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    }
  },
  [
    [\vals{a}{b}{c}
      [
        [\vals{Node above}{auto-}{filled}]
      ]
    ]
    [\vals{d}{e}{f}]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

will produce

[image: Empty nodes are empty tables]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array,forest}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\vals}[3]{\hline#1\\\hline#2\\\hline#3\\\hline}
\forestset{
  forest table/.style={
    align={|C{#1}|},
    inner sep=0pt,
    before typesetting nodes={
      if content={}{
        shape=coordinate
      }{},
    },
    draw
  },
  forest tables/.style={
    forest table=#1,
    delay={
      if content={}{
        content={\vals{}{}{}},
      }{}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    forest table=10mm
  }
  [
      [\vals{a}{b}{c}]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    font=\ttfamily,
    forest table=25mm,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    }
  },
  [\vals{}{}{}
    [\vals{a}{b}{c}
      [
        [\vals{Node above}{deliberately}{left empty}]
      ]
    ]
    [\vals{d}{e}{f}]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    font=\ttfamily,
    forest tables=10mm,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    }
  },
  [
    [\vals{a}{b}{c}
      [
        [\vals{Node above}{auto-}{filled}]
      ]
    ]
    [\vals{d}{e}{f}]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative solution. However, empty nodes doesn't produce a table.

Comment: @adn You didn't ask that they should. That is, that is not in the question. An alternative to what? You can, as pointed out, avoid **forest**'s tables by not setting `align` and use multi-part nodes. But if you really want tables, it seems daft to me not to use the fact that multi-line nodes are *already* tables.

Comment: @adn As I understood it, you wanted to get tables when you used a command in a node e.g. `\vals{a}{b}{c}`. My solution provides that. `\vals{a}{b}{c}` works and so does `\vals{}{}{}`. If you don't use `\vals...`, I assumed that you did not want a table. It is easy enough to make empty nodes produce one, but you need to be clear about what you want since what you want is apparently not what you said you wanted in the question.

Comment: @adn Please see edited answer. I've tried to make the existing code more flexible, removed a spurious usage of excess arguments and tried to improve the appearance of the output. I've also added a new style which allows you to say that you want empty nodes to be turned into empty tables.